# How can load url for type html in WebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I want to load a URL string of html type like this: "http://www. ....... .html" in WebView.
I tried the following code but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me, please?

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.link]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *url = self.link;
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<script>window.location=%@;</script>",
                             [[NSString alloc]
                               initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization
                                             dataWithJSONObject:url
                                             options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                             error:NULL]
                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              ]
                    baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Save the link as ".html" and add to your project.
then do this.

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

**EDIT**

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Link.html"]; 
    NSString*content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error]; 
  [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: i can't save html string in project, because is changing every time. i have many string like this.

Comment: can you review your code? I don't think is good. Who is htmlString and error?

Comment: i didn't get you.. please explain... the code works fine.

Comment: Not working. (lldb) po self.link
http://www.libe.ma/​Le-MAT-attendu-aujourd-hui-au-Caire_a63596.html

(lldb) po url
 nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81393/discussion-between-gaby-fitcal-and-dheeraj).